# Windows Server 2008 R2 - setting up a web server from scratch

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, iis

I just purchased a windows server 2008 R2 dedicated server from a local vendor. The server will also include SQL Server Web Edition Licence.

I have so little experience on servers and a little above basic info on IIS. I will be ruining asp.net applications on our server and there will be about 13 applications running on the server.

So where should I start here? should I firstly install IIS from control panel? or should I firstly install DNS server?

Comment: You should verify that the local vendor is selling you an authentic copy of windows.  AFAIK the web edition is a seperate server- not a license you add on to server 2008.  Web edition has some specific usage restrictions.

Comment: Honestly, call a consultant.

Comment: Windows web edition does not support the DNS role. Not quite sure why you would like DNS role on a pair of web and sql servers..

Comment: 3molo, that changed after it was released.  Web edition does support DNS role now.

Comment: thanks guys. the windows server is not web edition ! SQL server is. Windows Server 2008 R2 is Standard edition. I know I don't know much about this server issue but that would be great to know. I have purchased this server in order to learn about servers mostly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely outsource DNS.  Get a vendor like dyndns.com and have them point to your IP addresses(s).  If you're going to handle this yourself then keep to just the IIS website/application part of it.

I've been working on a 52 week series for the web pro.  I walk through host headers, IIS in depth, DNS and various other tools and tricks for the web pro.  You may find this useful to answer a number of your 'getting started' (and then more advanced) questions.

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/tags/Web+Pro+Series/default.aspx

Comment: thanks a lot. the blog posts looks great. I am checking them out now. on the other hand, I guess this server issue is too much for me to handle at the beginning level I guess. what do you think? is such a thing can be improved by practicing on the server?

Comment: Hi @tugberk.  Everyone has to start at some point, so don't worry about that.  You'll learn quickly.  However, if you don't have a real reason to do it yourself then this is something that does very well outsourced (web host, etc).  There is a LOT to consider for managing a secure and stable website, so it's not for the faint of heart, especially if you don't have someone that you work with that already knows this area.  That's your call.  You know your setup and reasons better than anyone else.

Comment: hi @scott. thanks a lot for your help. I'll start with your series and move forward from there.

Comment: @tugberk install plesk or some other related software. That's the easiest way. There are some opensource stuff like WebSitePanel as well