# configure a website with DNS names on IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, iis, iis-7

I know how to set up an application on IIS 7 but I don't know how to run it through the web, I mean how can I configure it with DNS names?

I will be using windows server 2008 R2 standard edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're asking but to make the web site available on the internet you need to do a few things:

1. You need to have a valid, registered domain.
2. You need externally available name servers to service the domain (the DNS zone).
3. You need an A or CNAME record that points your web site (www.mydomain.com) to an ip address that's been allocated to you by your ISP.
4. You need to create a rule in your firewall that allows web traffic (TCP port 80) from the outside to the internal ip address of your web server. Depending on your firewall you may need a NAT/Service rule or a port forwarding rule.

Comment: thanks for the answer. you might be right. I even don't know how to ask what I want to accomplish here. I actually brought a new dedicated server from a local vendor. they set it up and hand it to me. that is all it has for now. don't know how to start here. I asked another question here for that as well : http://serverfault.com/questions/266205/windows-server-2008-r2-setting-up-a-web-server-from-scratch

Comment: so, what is the role of IIS in this process? how does it map to correct application in the IIS?

Comment: If it's the only web site in IIS then all requests would be handled by that web site. If you have multiple web sites listening on the same port in IIS then you would use host headers (www.myotherdomain.com) to differentiate each site in IIS.

Comment: thanks for your help. I will have multiple web sites listening on the same port as far as I can describe. for example, I will have www.example.com which will use port 80 for http and www.example1.com which will use port 80 for http and port 443 for https. In this case should I use host headers on the IIS? so then, request which has been made to my domain or IP address would map to that web site on IIS?

Comment: I'm assuming you'll be running each web site on the same ip address and since you've stated that you'll be using port 80 for both sites then you will need to configure host headers for each site.